# Can't connect to SVN with tortoise svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a server with SVN installed

Lately, I installed a new router in the office (D-Link) and ever since then - I can't connect to the SVN remotely using tortoise SVN (connecting the server directly to the internet solves the issue)

The weird thing is that when the server is connected through the router I can access the repository through the browser (e.g. `http://myip:8081/svn/project`), but still can't connect through the tortoise repo-browser (the following error message appears: `Error running context: The server unexpectedly closed the connection`).

Of course I added port-forwarding from 8081 to the SVN server, but no luck.

thanks

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249097/) might help (not a duplicate). Maybe Tortoise tries to connect using the svn protocol and the router is blocking that port.

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge I tried adding port 3690 and now the SVN gets stuck when i'm trying to access the repository from the browser... i'm still buffeling with this issue, it drives me nuts! everything seems to be configured correctly

Comment: It might be worth asking this question on serverfault.com instead. You'll get better help there if it's a router configuration issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, my ISP blocked the access to some 'suspicious' protocols (one of the was webdav). don't know why they thought I need that kind of protection and why they didn't let me know it's there... anyway, now everything's back to normal

Comment: How did u clear this ISP issue, even i am facing same thing...I am using PPPOE in my router to connect with my ISP. Does PPPOE block any of the ports.

Comment: Your ISP's IT team should help you with that