# Access SVN server on Raspberry Pi from the outside

Tags: svn, raspberry-pi, portforwarding

I've made an SVN server using my Raspberry Pi. The SVN server works perfectly, but I want to have access to it from outside my ISP.

I know that I have to implement port forwarding in my router, but which port uses SVN and how can I manage to have some security over this service?

Comment: Does this question replies to your question ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249097/what-ports-need-to-be-open-for-svn-tortoise-to-authenticate-clear-text-and-com