# Can't connect to host 'app-dev.example.com': A connection attempt failed error while accessing svn repo

Tags: svn

I have created svn repo setup in linux machine and ran `svnserve -d` . But while trying to access from tortoise svn (from windows) using the command `svn://app-dev.example.com/svn/svnrepo` it says can't connect to host.

ping app-dev.example.com is working fine.

Did I miss any step?

**EDIT :** Now I am trying with Apache server to access via HTTP . I can access with the command `"sudo svn co --username user1 http://app-dev.example.com/svn/svnrepo"` in ubuntu itself (where I have created the repo) . But not from windows. I get error as "Unable to connect to a repository at URL.Connection timed out"

Comment: Firewall? -----

Comment: ping is working fine and giving results

Comment: The `svn:` protocol uses TCP [port 3690](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249097/what-ports-need-to-be-open-for-svn-tortoise-to-authenticate-clear-text-and-com). The `ping` command uses [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol), which doesn't have the concept of ports. You can't use the latter to diagnose the former.

Comment: how can I check that ? telenet host 3690 gives me the result as "Connecting To host...Could not open connection to the host, on port 3690: Connect failed"

Comment: Try to find an item called "firewall" in your Linux box menus. (I assume it works fine from local.)

Comment: yeah . It works fine from local (in linux).

Comment: @Alvaro Gonzalez  , I am trying with http option , still not possible to access from windows

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain myself properly. Computers have (or should have) a piece of security software called [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) that's designed to control network access. Whenever you want to accept incoming connections you need explicitly allow them in your firewall.