# Unable connect to the SVN server

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, smartsvn

I have SVN server and can connect to it from my work computer with TortoiseSVN. This is works fine. Also I have home notebook and from this notebook I can open this SVN using any web browser to view SVN content.

BUT I can't connect from home laptop to the SNV server using TortoiseSVN or SmartSVN: both programs return error: "Unable to connect to a repository at URL `http://<server name>`. Error running context: The server unexpectedly closed the connection". Previously this was worked.

Additional info:
When I type in TortoiseSVN Repo Browser `http://<server name>/<project>` this is show me subfolders of the project: branch, tags and trunk. But Repo browser don't show me content of this folders with the same error

Comment: Check maybe your / work firewall blocs the port of tortoise svn protocol. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249097/what-ports-need-to-be-open-for-tortoisesvn-to-authenticate-clear-text-and-comm)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, this was problem on the hoster side, 3 weeks and problem is solved!